# Coffeescript - How to apply closure and anonymous functions

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, react-rails

I am trying to pass the for loop variable as an argument to an onclick method in coffeescript as follows:

```
for index, option_value of @state.option_values
                  dom.span
                    key: "#{index} #{option_value.name}"
                    className: "pull-left col-md-3#{if option_value.selected then ' selected' else ''}"
                    onClick: () => @selectThis option_value


selectThis: (option_value_selected) ->
    alert(option_value_selected.name)
```

But `option_value` always refers to the last value of the `option_value` in `@state.option_values`. I know how to fix this in plain javascript. But, how to fix this in coffee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function:

```
onClick: () => @selectThis option_value
```

is is just storing the `option_value` reference that won't be evaluated until later when the `onClick` handler is called.

This is a pretty common problem with loops in JavaScript and CoffeeScript and the solution is the always the same: force the variable to be evaluated when the anonymous function is created. Your:

```
@selectThis.bind(null, option_value)
```

does that by calling the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function (but `@` will be `null` when the function is called so be careful).

A common idiom in JavaScript is to turn the loop body into a self invoking function:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    (function(i) { ... })(i)
```

to force the loop variable to be evaluated on each iteration. CoffeeScript has [`do` loops](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) as a shortcut for this idiom:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

An idiomatic CoffeeScript solution would look like:

```
for index, option_value of @state.option_values
  do (index, option_value) =>
    dom.span
      key: "#{index} #{option_value.name}"
      className: "pull-left col-md-3#{if option_value.selected then ' selected' else ''}"
      onClick: => @selectThis option_value
```

Comment: it is not working. leads to error `this.selectThis` is not a function

Comment: That's because the loop should be `do (index, option_value) =>` (to preserve `@` inside the SIF) rather than `do (index, option_value) ->`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, what is the difference between -> and => in coffee ?

Comment: `->` is just a normal function, `=>` binds the current `@` (AKA `this`) to the function: http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the correct syntax, sigh:

```
onClick: @selectThis.bind(null, option_value)
```